# How do i make my counter appear in my application through javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to javaFX and I wanted to make a simple code that counted how many times a person pressed a button and displayed the count on the application itself. Currently I have my code printing the counter in my IDE and would just like to some how attach it to the scene(eg I click run and every time I click the button it prints how many times I've clicked it in my workbench). I looked around stack overflow and youtube but the closest I got to what I was looking for was printing it in my IDE. Thanks for any help.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class JavaFXTest extends Application {
    private int counter = 0;


    public static void main (String [] args){
        Application.launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage = primaryStage;

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setPrefSize(400,400);

        Button button = new Button("Smash it!");
        HBox root = new HBox(5, pane);

        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            counter();
        });
        root.getChildren().add(button);

        Scene scene1 = new Scene(root,1000, 800, Color.AQUA);
        stage.setScene(scene1);
        stage.setTitle("ButtonSmash!");
        stage.show();


    }


    public void counter(){
        counter++;
        System.out.println(counter);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the full code:

```
package StackOverFlow;


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class JavaFXTest extends Application {
private int counter = 0;
private Label label = new Label("Count: ");

public static void main (String [] args){
    Application.launch();
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage = primaryStage;

    Pane pane = new Pane();
    pane.setPrefSize(400,400);

    Button button = new Button("Smash it!");
    HBox root = new HBox(5, pane);

    button.setOnAction(e -> {
        label.setText("Count: "+Integer.toString(counter));
        counter();
    });
    root.getChildren().add(button);
    label.relocate(0, 0); // You can put this label, wherever you want!
    root.getChildren().add(label);

    Scene scene1 = new Scene(root,1000, 800, Color.AQUA);
    stage.setScene(scene1);
    stage.setTitle("ButtonSmash!");
    stage.show();


}


public void counter(){
    counter++;
    //System.out.println(counter);

}
}
```

You had to make one label and to add it to your pane.getChildren();
And whenever you press the button you need to change text from that label.